# How do I find specific solutions of a system of equations with infinite solutions using sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

Here is my prompt: Use sympy to determine a set of solutions. For each set of solutions, provide at least two examples of solutions when there is more than one possible.

```
x,y,z = sy.symbols('x y z')
eq1 = sy.Eq(3*x + 4*y + z, x)
eq2 = sy.Eq(9*x + y - 4*(z**2),0)
result = sy.solve([eq1,eq2],(x,y,z))
print(result)
```

This code works, however I am struggling to figure out how to show the example solutions for the code. I can't use any assert claims since I'm not working with callable function, so I struggling to figure this part out.

Comment: Just substitute two different values for z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial at the link below seems to be saying that all the solutions will print out when there is more than one.  https://reliability.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Solving%20simultaneous%20equations%20with%20sympy.html

For example, this code prints out 6 results:

```
import sympy as sym
x,y,z = sym.symbols('x,y,z')
c1 = sym.Symbol('c1')
eq1 = sym.Eq(2*x**2+y+z,1)
eq2 = sym.Eq(x+2*y+z,c1)
eq3 = sym.Eq(-2*x+y,-z)
result = sym.solve([eq1,eq2,eq3],(x,y,z))
print(result)
```

Comment: yea, I have gotten results like that for other problems, but the result for this one gives [(z*(16*z + 1)/34, -z*(8*z + 9)/34, z)], which I am struggling to show examples of since I can't use assert to plug in values for z into my equation to show possible solutions for the system

Comment: When I change your last line to: result = sy.solve([eq1,eq2],(x,y,z==3)), I get an answer.  I'm no math expert (obviously).